# Icepick , project not build

Tags: android, android-build

Android Studio 3.0.1, Gradle 4.1, Java 1.8

In my project/build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    ext.ICEPICK = "3.2.0"

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {url "https://clojars.org/repo/"}
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

In my app/build.gradle:

```
implementation "frankiesardo:icepick:$ICEPICK"
compileOnly "frankiesardo:icepick-processor:$ICEPICK"
annotationProcessor "frankiesardo:icepick-processor:$ICEPICK"
```

But when I try to build my project I get error:

```
Error:Failed to resolve: frankiesardo:icepick-processor:3.2.0
<a href="openFile:myproject/app/build.gradle">Open File</a><br><a href="open.dependency.in.project.structure">Show in Project Structure dialog</a>
```

Comment: use like this
 `compileOnly 'frankiesardo:icepick-processor:'+rootProject.ICEPICK;`

Comment: Not help. Same result

Comment: did you add this in your gradle?
`repositories {
  maven {url "https://clojars.org/repo/"}
}`

Comment: yes, it's not help

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you add it to the right repositories section:

```
    buildscript {
        ext.ICEPICK = "3.2.0"

        repositories {
            google()
            jcenter()
            //Here is not good
        }
        dependencies {
            classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'


            // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
            // in the individual module build.gradle files
        }
    }

    allprojects {
        repositories {
            google()
            jcenter()
//add here
maven {url "https://clojars.org/repo/"}
        }
    }
```